# Samsung MFP (Multi Function Printer) Driver software, .ppd file

Tags: printing, samsung

Does anyone have any working LINUX driver software links for Samsung MFP printers? In particular, the MFP 2885-XAA?

The supposed all-in-one driver packages on Samsung's Support site either do not work at all, lack the 2885-XAA specific driver, or if you try to compile the package turns into a large pile of unusable mush.

The printer has integrated FAX and Scanner components and I am looking for a package that sees my printer-scanner-fax device as the multiple function equipment that it was sold to me as.

Thank you for your help folks. It has been a long run of workarounds and "Dry wells" trying to get this going properly and predictably.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this, I would go here https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-xpress-sl-m2885-laser-multifunction-printer-series/16462721/model/16462723

and click to download and SAVE what should be uld_v1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz

I would open a terminal; (control and alt and t keys all held down)

and copy each line below; and paste that line into the terminal; and hit the ENTER key

```
cd Downloads

tar -zxvf uld_v1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz

cd uld

sudo ./install.sh
```

and that should run the install script; and *should* set up a working driver

(best go to the PRINTERS folder before doing the above; delete any icons for the 2885; as you say they do not work; before running the above)